# Rails 3 and ActiveAdmin. How can I add a virtual model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Is ther a way to add a virtual model? Something such as a second dashboard where you can display more than one different resources?

I ask because I need to create a page with nothing but links to documents, like customer invoices, corporate invoices and other documents from other models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is to create some empty model:

app/models/fake.rb:

```
class Fake

end
```

then create generator app/models/fake.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Fake do
    config.comments = false
    config.clear_sidebar_sections!
    config.clear_action_items!

    collection_action :index do
        # here you can set you template
        render 'you_template', :layout => 'active_admin' 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The last changes in the master branch of ActiveAdmin deprecates the Dashboard and creates the concept of custom pages. See [this](http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-custom-pages.html) .